# markers is not being displayed

Tags: openlayers

I've exported OSM map. Made tiles using maperative. Now i wanted to add marker at a particular location. Above is the code for doing it. The marker doesn't display. Please give suggestions. I've taken code from a sample available on the net.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <TITLE>Simple Demo</TITLE>
   <style type="text/css">
   #map{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        position: absolute;
    }
   body{
        border: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
    }
   </style>
   <script src="OpenLayers.js"></script>
   <script src="OpenStreetMap.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var x=17.44458293043854;
        var y=78.34593429754106;
        function init(){
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',{ maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(78.336074588700086, 17.440730940004993, 78.36232312320854, 17.449071913098244),
                  numZoomLevels: 19,
                  maxResolution: 156543.0399,
                  units: 'm',
                  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
                  displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
                });

            var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("New Layer", "file://localhost/C:/Users/Pulkit/Downloads/OpenLayers-2.13.1/Tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 19});
            map.addLayer(newLayer);
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
            var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(78.349198855954313, 17.444901426551617).transform(map.displayProjection,  map.projection);
            if (!map.getCenter()) map.setCenter (lonLat, 11);

            var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
            map.addLayer(markers);
            markers.clearMarkers();
            var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
            var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
            var location = new OpenLayers.LonLat(17.44500562,78.34648309).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
            var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png', size, offset);

            markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(location,icon.clone()));

            //var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png', size, offset);

            //map.addLayer(markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(x, y),icon)));
            //markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(17.44458293043854,78.34593429754106),icon));
            //markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(new OpenLayers.LonLat(17.44458293043854,78.34593429754106),icon.clone()));
        }

        /*function loadMarker(){
            markers.clearMarkers();
            var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
            var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
            var location = new OpenLayers.LonLat(17.44500562,78.34648309).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject());
            var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png', size, offset);

            markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(location,icon.clone()));
        }*/

    </script>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY onload="init()">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check this piece of code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>OpenLayers Example with Marker</title>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        {
            var map, osm;
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
            osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
            map.addLayer(osm);
            var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"));
            var zoom = 4;
            map.setCenter(lonlat, zoom);
            var marker = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
            var size = new OpenLayers.Size(40, 40);
            var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w / 2), -(size.h / 2));
            var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png', size, offset);
            map.addLayer(marker);               
            var trackMarker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat, icon);
            marker.addMarker(trackMarker);
        }
        </script>
</body>
```